# Having problems with user input function with Python 2.7 and couldn't get those input to work with program

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-input, numerical-methods

I'm very new to python world though I've done a lot with php... and here's my case...

1. I'm writing some code for my little program with python 2.7.
2. In that program, I need to take 2 user input, both of them are numbers.
3. the first number must not be greater than 11 and must not be less than 0.
4. and second one must not be greater than 59 and must not be less than 0.
5. so first of all, I've to check both user input are valid and if they did wrong, program must give a warning to them and let them to try again.
6. finally, if they put both numbers correctly, I want to add those number and prompt a message like "The sum of your numbers is... blah... blah...".

So here is my code:

```
def validNum1(Num1):
    if Num1 < 0:
        print "%s is not valid value. Try again." % Num1
        return 0
    elif Num1 > 11:
        print "%s is not valid value. Try again." % Num1
        return 0
    else:
        return 1

def getInput_Num1():
    while 1:
        Num1 = raw_input("Enter Num1 Value: ")
        if validNum1(int(Num1)):
            break
    print "You're right. %s is a valid Num1." % Num1
    return
def validNum2(Num2):
    if Num2 < 0:
        print "%s is not valid value. Try again." % Num2
        return 0
    elif Num2 > 59:
        print "%s is not valid value. Try again." % Num2
        return 0
    else:
        return 2
def getInput_Num2():
    while 2:
        Num2 = raw_input("Enter Num2 Value: ")
        if validNum2(int(Num2)):
             break
    print "You're right. %s is a valid Num2." % Num2
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    getInput_Num1()
    getInput_Num2()
```

So now I think you guys get the idea 'bout what is needed to be filled; but let me make it more crystal clear. What I want to add to this program is an ability to add Num1 and Num2 and show the sum to the user.

Comment: Without going too far into changes, since you know that you can `return` a value from a function, what about having `getInput_Num*` return the number if it is indeed valid? Then you would have both numbers stored somewhere, after which you could sum/display.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to factor it down to two functions accepting parameters. This also means, that you can change the number of limits and their value by changing the list of  `limits` making your code more flexible. Also it uses new style string formatting that is much cleaner.

```
def validNum(num,limit):
    if 0< num <limit:
        print "{0} is a valid value.".format(str(num))
        return num
    print "{0} is not a valid value. Try again.".format(str(num))

def getInput(limits):
    results = []
    for limit in limits:
        while True:
            num = int(raw_input("Enter a numeric Value: "))            
            if validNum(num,limit):
                results.append(int(num))
                break   
    print 'The sum of chosen numbers is {0}'.format(str(sum(results)))

limits=[11,59]   
getInput(limits)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and merge all the functions in to one (I would say it makes it a lot cleaner), and then you can then add `Num1` and `Num2` and print the result.

```
def getInput():
    while True:
        Num1 = raw_input('Enter Num1 Value: ')
        if Num1 in range(12):
            print 'You're right. %s is a valid Num1.' % Num1
            break
        print '%s is not valid value. Try again.' % Num1
    while True:
        Num2 = raw_input('Enter Num2 Value: ')
        if Num2 in range(60):
            print 'You're right. %s is a valid Num2.' % Num2
            break
        print '%s is not valid value. Try again.' % Num2
    print 'The sum of your numbers is %s.' % (Num1 + Num2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    getInput()
```

However, if you don't want to change too much code, change the second `getInput` function so it accepts a parameter `Num1`, then make the first one call the second one with the parameter input as `Num1`. And then write a third function that accepts both numbers, adds them and prints the result. So like this:

```
getInput_Num2(Num1)  #add this to end of `getInput_Num1` function

def getInput_Num2(Num1):  #add a `Num1` parameter to pass to the new function

addNums(Num1, Num2)  #call the new function at the end of `getInput_Num2`

def addNums(Num1, Num2):
    print 'The sum of your numbers is %s.' % (Num1 + Num2)
    #do whatever else you want to do

if __name__ == '__main__':
    getInput_Num1()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend not making one function, but separating the concerns: you want input (twice, with different prompts), you want to validate, you want to multiply and you want to print the result. For the two latter, no function is necessary due to their low complexity. For the first two, create functions and **reuse them for num1 and num2**.

Try this:

```
def is_valid_number(number_str):
    try:
        number = int(number_str)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    if number < 0 or number > 11:
        return False
    else:
        return True

def get_input_number(prompt):
    while True:
        num = raw_input(prompt)
        if is_valid_number(num):
            return int(num)
        else:
            print "%s is not a valid value. Try again." % num

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num1 = get_input_number("Enter Num1 Value: ")    
    num2 = get_input_number("Enter Num2 Value: ")
    print "%i + %i = %i" % (num1, num2, num1+num2)
```

The main routine only has three lines, and each method does what its name indicates and is reusable.

Separation of concerns (SoC) is one main principle of software design, it makes code more readable, maintainable, elegant and less error-prone

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who might be looking for a more pythonic approach (python 3), you can try this:

```
def valid_nums():
    """Check for validity of user inputs."""
    num_1, num_2 = get_input()
    if (0 <= num_1 <= 11) and (0 <= num_2 <= 59):
        sum_of_nums = num_1 + num_2
        return "\nThe sum of {0} and {1} is {2}.\n".format(num_1, num_2, sum_of_nums)
    else:
        return "\n{0} or {1} is out of range.\n".format(num_1, num_2)

def get_input():
    """Accept user input."""
    while True:
        try:
            num_1 = int(input("Enter a number between 0 and 11: "))
            num_2 = int(input("Enter a number between 0 and 59: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("\nOne or more of your entry is invalid. Please try again.\n")
            continue
        else:
            return num_1, num_2

# Main program loop.
while True:
    print(valid_nums())
```